# c# vs java HMACSHA1

Tags: c#, java, sha1

I'm trying to implement this Java SHA1 in C#. Not sure why my results in C# are different.

I'm hesitant to post the key and data which create the hash, though filling in any value should produce differing results in each implementation.

Java:

```
String key = "key";
String data = "data";
String algorithm = "HmacSHA1";
Charset charset = Charset.forName("utf-8");
SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), algorithm);
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
mac.init(signingKey);
return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes(charset))), charset);
```

produces: g1SZb73Vg6bV7VhFQ2KkCLy98rE=

C#:

```
String key = "key";
String data = "data";
byte[] aKey = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
byte[] aData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
HMACSHA1 oEncode = new HMACSHA1(aKey);
byte[] aBytes = oEncode.ComputeHash(aData);
return Convert.ToBase64String(aBytes);
```

produces: 50Hg/Hsq4v+iYrXJYpxxHE5q3RU=

Comment: The C# code is correct. I can't vouch either way for your Java implementation. If you could post the full code somewhere (e.g. pastebin) it might give us a better idea as to why it's not working.

Comment: Not related to your question: While using `UTF8Encoding.UTF8` is correct, it's very misleading and you should use `Encoding.UTF8` instead. It looks quite right in this case, but `UTF8Encoding.Unicode`, or, worse, `UTF8Encoding.Default` could confuse someone a lot.

Comment: You aren't encoding your key using utf-8 in Java. Might be a problem.

Comment: Start by verifying (logging) aKey and aData in both situations. They have to match bit for bit.

Comment: Closest I could get on ideone... {sigh}.  [Java (doesn't run)](http://www.ideone.com/sPbMN), [C# (works)](http://www.ideone.com/UIFMD).  I'm reminded again why I like .Net better than Java :-)

Comment: @Guvante - Any guess at what encoding to attempt for the key, I have to create the same hash as the Java version, the required output is out of my control.

Comment: You should be called `key.getBytes(charset)` I believe, but I haven't done any Java security stuff before.